# How to identify ancient KornShell version?

Tags: shell, ibm, aix, unix-shell, ksh

We had a guy retire on us, and the documentation left behind is a little on the light side. Need a little help identifying and using part an older client-server system.

The server itself is maintained by several excellent Unix admins. We are currently running AIX 7.1.0.0 on the server side.

However, when we log in using the proprietary SSH client, we are greeted with a shell that looks familiar, but is strange in other ways. The shell itself seems to be KornShell:

```
echo $0
-ksh
```

But the shell doesn't respond to normal shell commands (cannot tap up/down to recall recent commands, cannot backspace normally, no auto-complete with tab, etc.)

Recent commands are recalled using <kbd>ESC + k</kbd>

If the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key is tapped, the terminal stops responding to input until <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, or <kbd>cc</kbd> are pressed (or <kbd>k</kbd>, as already mentioned brings up the most recent command).

To edit a recalled command we have to tap <kbd>SHIFT + UP</kbd>

Backspace is actually the <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> arrow, and to clear a typed command we have to hit <kbd>SHIFT + RIGHT</kbd>

The `whence` command is not available, and none of the techniques to discover the KSH version on [this page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-appleosx-get-ksh-version-check-ksh-version/) worked.

Someone in our office suggested this is some kind of inline `vi`.

**Does anyone else have any advice? Is there any documentation available?**

Comment: probably a combination of `set -o vi` (you can get back with `set -o emacs`) and some incorrectly set `$TERM` variable (not matching the terminal emulation emulated by your SSH client).

Comment: @mihi This does favorably change the way the shell responds. Still having trouble figuring out how recent commands can be recalled (the Up arrow is not working), but at least the backspace key works normally.

Comment: You should check out `~/.profile, ~/.kshrc, /etc/profile` and the value of `$ENV`. Also read the man page for ksh.  You will then find where `set -o vi` is being run among many other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

or

<kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

This was discovered on a related question on the Unix & Linux SE:

[How can I safely get the version of ksh? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199900/how-can-i-safely-get-the-version-of-ksh/199972#199972)

This revealed that we are running

> Version M-11/16/88f

Maybe it's not that ancient after all!

Comment: As it turns out, your friendly Unix admins can install an up-to-date version of `bash` on AIX 7.1 by request. ksh is dead; long live ksh~

Answer (score 4):

Try `what $(which ksh)`

For example, on a Solaris 8 box:

```
$ what $(which ksh)
/usr/bin/ksh:
        Version M-11/16/88i
        SunOS 5.8 Generic 110662-24 Apr 2007
```

Comment: For this, I get a huge, vomitous mass of information, 40+ lines long, mostly .c libraries. At the very end, there is an entry for `vi.c, cmdksh, aix71B 1040A_71B` followed by a datestamp from the year 2010.

Comment: search through the spew for the `88` or `93` to see if you can narrow down the ksh version.

Comment: And, I just had the same thought as mihi above: `set -o emacs`

Comment: Really want to accept this answer. You still get my upvote. Even though this did not directly solve the problem, it still was extremely helpful. The command suggested actually works -- unlike many of the other suggestions around the webs. Thank you. You are a gentleman and a scholar.